# Delete <dt> without <dd> with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a definition list and I need to delete all the `<dt>` tags who doesn't have any `<dd>`
In this particular case: Herramientas, Suplementos, Repuestos, Herramientas and Anti pinchaduras

The list can vary wildly because it's stock dependent (any category `<dt>` can get empty)

I tried this

```
$('dt+dt').each(function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

But it deletes "partes" instead of "herramientas" and fails to delete "suplementos"
Also tried with `:empty` but it seems like a dt without a dd isn't considered empty...

There must be a extremely simple and easy solution but my brain refuses to see it :-(

Example list:

```
<dl>
    <dt>Bicicletas</dt>
        <dd><a href="/bicicletas/">Bicicletas</a> (70)</dd>
    <dt>Accesorios</dt>
        <dd><a href="/accesorios/bocinas/">Bocinas, timbres y cornetas</a> (9)</dd>
        <dd><a href="/accesorios/transporte/">Transporte y protección</a> (1)</dd>
    <dt>Herramientas</dt>
    <dt>Partes</dt>
        <dd><a href="/partes/cubiertas/">Cubiertas</a> (2)</dd>
        <dd><a href="/partes/asientos/">Asientos</a> (5)</dd>
        <dd><a href="/partes/grips/">Puños / grips</a> (1)</dd>
    <dt>Articulos de indumentaria</dt>
        <dd><a href="/indumentaria/jerseys/">Jerseys / Remeras</a> (1)</dd>
        <dd><a href="/indumentaria/cascos/">Cascos</a> (3)</dd>
    <dt>Suplementos</dt>
    <dt>Repuestos</dt>
    <dt>Herramientas</dt>
    <dt>Anti pinchaduras</dt>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('dt').filter(function(){
                     return !($(this).next().is('dd'));
               }).remove();
```

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/isute

---

This can also work, but is weird, and will not select the last `<dt>`, so I've added anothe selector:

```
$('dt + dt').prev().add('dt:last-child').remove();
```

That is: select all `<dt>`s that are after another `<dt>`, select the prev dt, and add the last.

---

Another option:

```
var good = $('dd').prev('dt');
$('dt').not(good).remove();
```

[`not` can take an array](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not#expr), so this works. This can also be written as 
$('dt').not($('dd').prev('dt')).remove();, but is very ugly.

Comment: I should add - originally I did `$('dt + :not(dd)').prev()` , so the dt:last-child made more sense - it is last, or it has something that isn't a dd after it.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
$('dt').each(function() {
    if($(this).next('dd').length == 0){
       $(this.remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('dl>dt').each(function() {
    if ($(this).next("dd").length <= 0){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: This removes all dts that don’t *contain* a dd. That is, probably all of them. -1

Comment: Your first selector is `dl>dt` - you begin with an empty set, there's no hierarchy here :P . See the link I have on my answer? add `/edit` to the end and play with it, you'll see what I mean (that's http://jsbin.com/isute/edit ).

Answer (score 0):

This will work for hidden `<dd>` as well:

```
var $dl = $('dl'); // hook this up to your DL

$dl.find('dt').each(function() {
  var $dt = $(this), $next = $dt.nextAll(':visible').slice(0,1);
  // the next visible element is a dt OR there isn't another visible element.
  if ($next.slice(0,1).is('dt') || $next.length == 0)
  {
    $dt.hide();
  } else {
    $dt.show();
  }
});
```