# Jquery dt class dependent on dd ol css style

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a dlist, where I want to add a class to "dt" if the next "dd ol" is hidden.

In The exsample below you see dd.dd2 ol is hidden, so I want the dt above, to collapse (add a class)

I found this on Stackoverflow: [Delete <dt> without <dd> with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957675/delete-dt-without-dd-with-jquery)

```
$('dt').filter(function(){
                     return !($(this).next().is('dd'));
               }).remove();
```

and tried something similar:

```
$('#someID dt').filter(function(){
                     return ($(this).next().is('dd ol').css('display') == 'none');
               }).addClass('collapsed');
```

HTML:

```
<dl id="someID">
<dt class="dt1">List1<span>&nbsp;</span></dt>
<dd class="dd1" >
<ol>
<li class="listitem1"><a href="#" title="listitem1">listitem1</a></li>
<li class="listitem2"><a href="#" title="listitem2"><span class="txt">listitem2</span></a></li>
<li class="listitem3"><a href="#" title="listitem3"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span><span class="txt">listitem3</span></a></li>
</ol>
</dd>

<dt class="dt2">List2<span>&nbsp;</span></dt>
<dd class="dd2" >
<ol style="display: none;">
<li class="listitem1"><a href="#" title="listitem1">listitem1</a></li>
<li class="listitem2"><a href="#" title="listitem2"><span class="txt">listitem2</span></a></li>
<li class="listitem3"><a href="#" title="listitem3"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span><span class="txt">listitem3</span></a></li>
</ol>
</dd>

<dt class="dt3">List3<span>&nbsp;</span></dt>
<dd class="dd3" >
<ol>
<li class="listitem1"><a href="#" title="listitem1">listitem1</a></li>
<li class="listitem2"><a href="#" title="listitem2"><span class="txt">listitem2</span></a></li>
<li class="listitem3"><a href="#" title="listitem3"><span class="icon">&nbsp;</span><span class="txt">listitem3</span></a></li>
</ol>
</dd>
</dl>
```

But it didn't work out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach is to use the [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/):

```
$('dl#someID dd ol:hidden').parent().prev('dt').addClass('collapsed');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/mULNu/

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your filter function:

```
return $(this).next().is('dd').has('ol:hidden').length > 0;
```